# http.post() not posting even though url is correct

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers

I am designing something that will take a function and activate it; upSwipe(). When called I want to post to the url: http://localhost:8000/areas/fun/736993854/spread/1/ with an empty body. The console outputs the correct url as above in this post. However the same line of code below, the http.post is not working/not posting. I am not quite sure why.
Any help here?

```
    ﻿import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Post} from '../_models/index';
    import { AuthenticationService, PostService, SpreadService, AreaService} from '../_services/index';

    @Component({
        templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
    })

    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      posts: Post[] = [];

      constructor(private http: Http,
      private postService: PostService,
      private spreadService: SpreadService,
      private areaService: AreaService,
      private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
            // get posts from secure api end point
            this.postService.getPosts()
                .subscribe(post => {
                    this.posts =  post;
                });
        }

      upSwipe() {
          console.log('upSwipe worked');
          const headers = new Headers();

          headers.append('Authorization', 'token ' + this.authenticationService.token);
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        const options = new RequestOptions({

        headers: headers,


        });
          // get areas from api
          console.log('http://localhost:8000/areas/' + this.areaService.currentAreaName + '/' + this.posts[0].id + '/spread/1/');
          this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/areas/' + this.areaService.currentAreaName  + '/' + this.posts[0].id + '/spread/1/', {}, options);
          this.ngOnInit();
            }

      downSwipe() {
        console.log('downSwipe worked');
      }

      fun() {
        this.areaService.currentArea = 0;
        this.areaService.currentAreaName = 'fun';
        this.ngOnInit();
      }

      information() {
        this.areaService.currentArea = 1;
        this.areaService.currentAreaName = 'information';
        this.ngOnInit();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.post` returns an `Observable` and Observables don't start emitting until they are subscribed. Try this:

```
this.http.post(url, {}, options).subscribe(
 data => console.log(data)
);
```